# como ocultar icono en el laucher de android

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y ya la he terminado. Sólo necesito saber cómo es la manera de ocultar la aplicación del launcher.

Es decir, la aplicación que se abra una vez y se oculte, o sea que no se muestre en el cajón de apps de Android.

Encontré este código por la web y no sé cómo implementarlo

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), 
                              PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
                              PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Cual es tu objetivo de esto, si no aparece en la pantalla como podrías abrirla, que deseas hacer amigo?

Comment: osea una vez instalada la app que se habra una vez y luego se oculte del launcher encotre este codigo por la web y no se como inplementearlo |:  .java PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Comment: Hola @matias. ¿ **Para qué** querrías que se oculte?

Comment: hola mariano estoy desarrollado una aplicacion de pentestin haciendo pruebas sobre espionaje en android ya esta el codigo estaba bien solamente me equivoque en el lugar donde iva

Comment: Entiendo lo que realizas, solo recuerda que este tipo de aplicaciones se reportan y regularmente las dan de baja.

Answer (score 1):

Tu necesidad es crear una aplicación que sea instalada y que no se vea el icono.

Agrega esto dentro de tu método `onCreate()` pero recuerda algo importante, el icono  se mostraría hasta que el usuario realice un restart:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("[Paquete de aplicación]","[Paquete de aplicación].LauncherActivity");
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```